# Change function of the pgdown key

Tags: web

Is there a way to change the function of the pgdown key so that, when users are on your site, pressing pgdown takes the user to a particular anchor on the page?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with JS like this:

```
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    if (e.which === 40) {
        window.location.href = "#" + ancohr;
    }
})
```

Adding the event listener to the window will catch any keydown event, `40` is `arrow down` key code, then you send the client where you want with adding the anchor to the current root location.